# Get text inside parentheses with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

So I am trying to write the regular expression for this string:

```
changed 55 (test)
```

so basically whenever an item is changed on our system, their name gets changed to

```
changed ID (NAME)
```

I would like to use preg_match to get the name of the item.

So if the string is

```
changed 1000 (Jesus)
```

I want to be able to get Jesus

if the string is

```
changed 9000 (Dicaprio)
```

I want to be able to get Dicaprio

How can I do that?

Problem is that the name can be  )()Dicaprio

so if its changed to

```
changed 32 ()()Dicaprio)
```

I still need to get back ")()Dicaprio" (without the quotes)

Comment: Trivial: `/\(.*\)/`. Slightly less trivial: `/(?<\().*(?=\))/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/changed (\d+) \((.*)\)/
                  ^^----- Contents within the parentheses
                ^-----^-- outer parentheses

         ^^^^^----------- The number
```

```
<?php

$subject = 'changed 32 ()()Dicaprio)';
$pattern = '/changed (\d+) \((.*)\)/';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output for `)()Dicaprio` (see [online @ eval.in](https://eval.in/58084)):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "changed 32 ()()Dicaprio)"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "32"
  [2]=>
  string(11) ")()Dicaprio"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$text = 'changed 9000 (Dicaprio)';
preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $text, $aryMatches);
echo $aryMatches[1];
```

**EDIT**: Okay, you need this instead:

```
$text = 'changed 9000 ()()Dicaprio)';
preg_match('/\((.+)\)/', $text, $aryMatches);
echo $aryMatches[1];
```

Comment: Problem is the name can be  )()Dicaprio, if its changes I still want to get,  )()Dicaprio

Answer (score 1):

Input: 'changed 1000 (Jesus)'

```
preg_match("/changed .* \((.*)\)/i", $input_line, $output_array);

Array
(
    [0] => changed 1000 (Jesus)
    [1] => Jesus
)
```

Demo:  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1JZ

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extract of [php.net documentation of preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) :

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Example :

```
[neumann@MacBookPro ~]$ cat test.php 
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $str = "changed 1000 (Dicaprio)";
    $pattern = "/changed [0-9]+ \(([A-Za-z]+)\)/";
    $result = array();

    preg_match($pattern, $str, $result);
    var_dump($result);
?>

[neumann@MacBookPro ~]$ ./test.php 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "changed 1000 (Dicaprio)"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Dicaprio"
}
```

So you could use `$result[1]` to get the name ;)